# database table schema to store object-like dynamic attribute

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple YAML.

```
- name: name_1 
  k1: v1_1 
  k2: v2_1 
  k3: v3_1
- name: name_2 
  k1: v1_2 
  k2: v2_2 
  k3: v3_2
- name: name_3
  k1: v1_3 
  k2: v2_3 
  k3: v3_3
```

The attributes' name might vary by different projects.

I want to put this yaml data to sqlite database. So, I create two table: `obj` and `attr`

```
Table:obj

obj_id      name      
----------  ----------
1           name_1    
2           name_2    
3           name_3    

Table: attr

id          obj_id      key         value     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           k1          v1_1      
2           1           k2          v2_1      
3           1           k3          v3_1      
4           2           k1          v1_2      
5           2           k2          v2_2      
6           2           k3          v3_2      
7           3           k1          v1_3      
8           3           k2          v2_3      
9           3           k3          v3_3
```

And I want to have output like the bellowing:

```
obj_id      name        k1          k2          k3        
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           name_1      v1_1        v2_1        v3_1      
2           name_2      v1_2        v2_2        v3_2      
3           name_3      v1_3        v2_3        v3_3
```

I use this query:

```
select * 
from 
    obj 
    natural join (select obj_id, value as k1 from attr where key = 'k1' ) 
    natural join (select obj_id, value as k2 from attr where key = 'k2' ) 
    natural join (select obj_id, value as k3 from attr where key = 'k3' ) 
;
```

This could generate the output, quite a lot of words. 
Moreover, in another project, attribute names may change, let's say the attribute might be  (k4, k5, k6). 
I have to re-write this query again.

I have two questions:

1. Any better query syntax to make this more elegant?
2. Any better query syntax let query suitable for any projects which key may vary?

Comment: `.dump` please. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Would a single column `kn` with in each row a comma separated list of all ks be OK?